# How to move Joomla 1.5?

Tags: php, apache, joomla

I've read a lot on the internet about how to move Joomla. So, confident in myself, I've moved this old joomla 1.5 website to another machine.

I've copied files and database (data and user) as it were in the old machine on the new. Same folder name, same apache2 configuration, same .htaccess, same database configuration, name and data, same operative system, same php version...

Unfortunately, any page I'm trying to visit return a "404 component not found error" like it cannot find the page.

I cannot get what is happening. Mooving Joomla requires particular attentions, after copying files and database?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change in configuration.php file the path of log and tmp directory, It's hard for you to have the same path in a different machine.
In the log file there are more details? Type what component.

Comment: Why should they not be the same? logs and tmp path are in the same directory of joomla website... In the directory log, I have no logs, neither there is a more precise error log in apache error log

Comment: Not the same because you can put the path of your fisical server. Try to disable the external component of joomla or to put it in xampp installation to see if you have the same problem.

Comment: Ok. Actually, now I cannot access anything in the website. Any page return that component not found error, so I'm not sure how to disable things. Enabling debug reported "Component Not Found

Call stack #  Function  Location 
1  JSite->dispatch()  /var/www/html/mysite/index.php:68 
2  JComponentHelper->renderComponent()  /var/www/html/mysite/includes/application.php:124"

Answer (score 0):

Some things to check when a moved Joomla website is not working as expected:

- the .htaccess file (in particular, check the `RewriteBase /`, `Options +FollowSymLinks` lines or any non-standard lines - compare with htaccess.txt for the default settings)
- the configuration.php file, check tmp and logs paths are correct, try setting `$live_site = '';` if it's not already
- check for any `php.ini` files in the root folder and also in the /administrator folder - `php.ini` files are often not needed any more as you can configure PHP settings via cPanel or similar
- try disabling URL Rewriting in Global Configuration